# Customization of windows 10 Start menu - can i delete the list of programs?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, start-menu, modern-ui, desktop-customization

Can i fully delete last apps/most used/recently added panel from the left side of windows 10 start menu and save only space for metro apps? Like a small, windowed version of start menu in windows 8.1?

Comment: I don't think there is a native way to do that. FYI, you can expand the "Metro" apps section by grabbing the right edge and dragging. This will give you more space for apps/live tiles.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but i hope, that some tweak can do this. I need no expanding of start menu, i want to hide unneeded (for me) blocks.

Comment: You can't delete / remove the "all programs" I don't think (I could be wrong).

You can remove the "Recently used" section. It is under start - settings - Personalisation - Start. You can turn off most used apps, and recently added apps, and even "show suggestions". Or if you like the Windows 8.1 start menu style, you can use the "Use Start full screen" which gives you Windows 8.1 style start menu.

Comment: There is no way to make the start menu on Windows 10 1607 to work like the start menu on 8.1 Update 1

Comment: Any third-party app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, Microsoft added this feature in *Creators Update*. It's possible to choose preferred view by using buttons in left side of start menu.